# How to enter password in command promt using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have written vb script code to copy files from Windows to Linux using putty PSCP command

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "cmd /K pscp.exe c:\temp\sunset.jpg tokunbo@my-ipaddress:/home/tokunbo"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

When i am running above script,i am getting tokunbo@my-ipaddress password: option in command promt. My question how to write code to enter password in command prompt in vbscript. Please help

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage):

```
Usage: pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
       pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
       pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:filespec
Options:
  -V        print version information and exit
  -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
  -p        preserve file attributes
  -q        quiet, don't show statistics
  -r        copy directories recursively
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -1 -2     force use of particular SSH protocol version
  -4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for authentication
  -noagent  disable use of Pageant
  -agent    enable use of Pageant
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
  -unsafe   allow server-side wildcards (DANGEROUS)
  -sftp     force use of SFTP protocol
  -scp      force use of SCP protocol
```

I would, however, recommend using [public key authentication](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant) instead of password authentication.